Microsoft Azure Function App broken after upgrade to .NET 8
I've upgrade my projects to .NET 8. Everything is working locally, but when I deploy it to Microsoft Azure, the Function App throws the following error:

System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz123'.

I was able to upgrade all the NuGet packages to the latest version except for Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect. If this gets upgraded to a later version than 7.1.2, it crashes locally, so I skipped this for now.
My .csproj of my startup project looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
      <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
      <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.37" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.16.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="PdfPig" Version="0.1.8" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="blmgencmd.exe">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="host.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="local.settings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </None>
      <None Update="msvcr110d.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
       <ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.csproj" />
       //here are some more
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

When I try to fetch data from the Function App it now returns:

503 Service unavailable - Function host is not running.

The Function App is also set to .NET 8 in the configuration.
Does anyone have an idea of what could be the issue with this or put me on the right track?
Big Thanks!

Please provide your function code along with .csproj.

I've added the .csproj of the startup project. There are 72 projects so I can't include them all.  I'm not sure what you want me to share as my function code.

What type of Functions are you intending using in .NET 8 - are you trying to use Isolated or In-process?

If you're not sure how to answer my above comment, maybe show relevant parts of your startup class (e.g. Program.cs) into your question.
